# jq split string and assign

Tags: json, jq

I have the following json

```
{
    "version" : "0.1.2",
    "basePath" : "/"
}
```

and the desired output is

```
{
    "version" : "0.1.2",
    "basePath" : "beta1"
}
```

I have the following jq which is producing the error below:

```
.basePath = .version | split(".") as $version | if  $version[0] == "0" then "beta"+ $version[1] else $version[0] end
```

jq: error (at :3): split input and separator must be strings
exit status 5

Using `.basePath = .version` assigns the value successfully and `.version | split(".") as $version | if  $version[0] == "0" then "beta"+ $version[1] else $version[0] end` on its own returns `"beta1"`.  Is there a way to assign the string to the `basePath` key?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Good news! Your proposed solution is just missing a pair of parentheses.  Also, there is no need for `$version`.  That is, this will do it:

```
.basePath = (.version | split(".")
             | if .[0] == "0" then "beta"+ .[1] else .[0] end)
```